# execute php statement if javascript condition is true

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement, conditional-statements, execute

I'm trying to execute a php statement if my javascript condition is true so i write this little code :

```html
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox"> MSI<br></input>
```

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
          if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')) <?php echo "Bonjour le monde";?>;

 });
});
</script>
```

But this don't work, if someone can help me it will be great.

Comment: PHP runs on the server side, so it will run before the html/js is server (and parsed) by the browser. If you want to conditionally run some PHP in JS you will need to send an ajax request to a server side script that may conditionally return some data.

Comment: @JimL and how to request an ajax to a server because i really don't now

Answer (score 0):

Use onChange and a function

```
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" onChange='myFunction()'> MSI<br></input>
```

```html
<script>
function myFunction() {
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
          if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')) <?php echo "Bonjour le monde";?>;

 });
});
}
</script>
```

'

Hopefully that will work

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP is evaluated on the server before the page is sent to your browser you should send a new request to the server and get a new page back with response.SO you should try something like this.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
     var checked = $('#checkbox1').is(':checked')
     $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: '/path/page.php',
         data: 'answer=' + answer,
         success: function(response) {
             if(response)
                 <?php echo "Bonjour le monde";?>;
         }
     });
```

});